# multiple typedef for same type

Tags: c++, stl, typedef

Below code is class initializer list which is provided in Ubuntu standard package. In this iterator and const_iterator are typedef of same type. I just wanted to know why would we like to have same typedef for different type of Iterator ?  Ideally for Iterator it should have typedef _E* iterator.

```
// In the class initializer list:
namespace std 
{ 
  /// initializer_list 
  template<class _E> 
    class initializer_list 
    { 
    public: 
      typedef _E                value_type; 
      typedef const _E&         reference; 
      typedef const _E&         const_reference; 
      typedef size_t            size_type; 
      typedef const _E*         iterator; 
      typedef const _E*         const_iterator;
```

P.S: I am not able to think of suitable title so I have given this title

Comment: I think `::reference` should be `typedef _E&` not `typedef const _E&`.

Comment: You don't want to be able to modify anything within the initializer_list object, but it requires ::reference in order to meet the requirements of the Container concept, so they mark it as const.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To meet the requirements for a [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container), both types `iterator` an `const_iterator` must exist. Many algorithms and lots of code rely on containers having both of these types available. There's no reason the `iterator` type has to be a non-`const` (mutable) iterator, however. In this case, they've decided that both `iterator` and `const_iterator` are `const` (immutable) iterators.

The reason they have both iterators as `const` is because they clearly don't want to you to be able to change the values in the `initializer_list`.

As another example of this, take a look at [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) whose `iterator` and `const_iterator` types are also both constant iterators. Since `std::set`s contain ordered elements, if you were to be able to change the contents of the `std::set`, that ordering would be invalidated. To prevent this, both iterator types are made immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Because these fields are required by any type that satisfies the requirements of [`Container`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container).  It just so happens that in the case of 
`std::initializer_list`, the `iterator` and the `const_iterator` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you don't ever want to change the values stored inside of an initializer list. They're meant to be temporary objects to be passed up into constructors.

C++ has an (informal, for now) ideal called Concepts that apply to generic types. The Container concept requires certain typedefs to be available for your object. Since std::initializer_list is a container, it requires both ::iterator and ::const_iterator typedefs. However, like std::set, you don't want to let the user modify the elements inside of the initializer_list, and so the ::iterator is the same as ::const_iterator: they're both read-only.